# What is the difference between Event Delivery and Event Publishing in Platform events?

Tags: platform-event, streaming-api

Around Platform event limits, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) currently states that the Event **Delivery** default limit is **50K/DAY** but Event **Publishing** limit is **100K/HR**. Note the limit is 48 times more for Publishing.

What does this actually mean? Does it mean that a huge number of Events can be published as long as nobody is subscribing to them?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, you don't need to worry about those particular limits. Those are for Standard-Volume Platform Events, and you can't create those anymore. All new platform events are high volume by default.

The difference between the publish and delivery is the actor of the action. For example: if a user updates a record's field to a certain value, you want the object's trigger to publish a new event that will be delivered to another implementation. The trigger **publishes** the event. The platform **delivers** the event to its subscribers.

Comment: ok lets day everything is High Volume, so limits are Event delivery 50K/Day and Event Publishing 250K/Hour. So if I create a Platform event and nobody subscribes to it then I can create 250K/hr??

Comment: yes even i am bit confused, any help would be appreciated. Why is there a higher Publishing limit than delivering, if i reach the 50K limit of delivery then does that mean my events will be created but not delivered - how does it behave once we hit the delivery limit

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) :

> The publishing allocation is how many events you can publish using any method, including Apex, APIs, flows, and processes.
>
> The delivery allocation is how many event notifications can be delivered to CometD subscribers, including the empApi Lightning component. It excludes non-CometD subscribers, such as Apex triggers, flows, and processes.
>
> The publishing allocation is higher than the delivery allocation because there can be various types of subscribers.

**Published event messages that are delivered to non-CometD subscribers, such as Apex triggers, flows, and processes, don’t count against the delivery allocation.**